# Using a variable in the WHERE clause causes the query to last forever

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue with using a variable in the `WHERE` clause of a mysql query. I tried searching google but could not find any answer.

At the start of a MySQL script, I assign some value into a variable and then use that variable at multiple places inside the query. At one specific subquery, if I use the variable, the query keeps on running but if I use the constant value of the variable instead, the query runs in a second.

Please have a look at the below example. Here I am using a variable `@maxid` in `WHERE` clause

```
set @maxid2 = '1001-a';
select distinct
    dc.db_date,
    dc.year_month,
    dc.year,
    dc.week,
    dc.day,
    dc.dayofweek - 1 as DayOfWeek,
    em.ID as EmployeeID,
    concat_ws(' ', em.`FirstName`, `LastName`) as EmployeeName
from
    datavis_cal dc
        cross join
    employees_data em ON em.ID = @maxid2
        and dc.db_date >= (select 
            min(assigndate)
        from
            attendance_data
        where
            ID = @maxid2)
        and db_date <= curdate()
        and em.DeptID = (select distinct
            DeptID
        from
            users
        where
            username = 'demo')
```

This code keeps on running and I have to cancel the query. Now have a look at the below query. It's the same query but here instead of the variable, I am using the constant value of the variable. I have replaced the variable `@maxid2` with its value `'1001-a'` in the script:

```
set @maxid2 = '1001-a';
select distinct
    dc.db_date,
    dc.year_month,
    dc.year,
    dc.week,
    dc.day,
    dc.dayofweek - 1 as DayOfWeek,
    em.ID as EmployeeID,
    concat_ws(' ', em.`FirstName`, `LastName`) as EmployeeName
from
    datavis_cal dc
        cross join
    employees_data em ON em.ID = '1001-a'
        and dc.db_date >= (select 
            min(assigndate)
        from
            attendance_data
        where
            ID = '1001-a')
        and db_date <= curdate()
        and em.DeptID = (select distinct
            DeptID
        from
            users
        where
            username = 'demo')
```

So my question is, what could the variable possibly be doing to the script that it keeps on running but the value of the variable gives result in a second?

Please let me know if I need to explain this more. I have tried many solutions and also searched google but could not find any answer for this.

Comment: The query optimizer knows that literals can never change, but variables can be reassigned. I guess it doesn't scan the query to tell that there's never an assignment to the variable.

Comment: So what solution can I use here? actually the value into the variable comes from a short query which is used at many places in the whole query. Therefore, instead of writing that subquery at every where condition, I want to runt his query once, assigned its max value into a variable and use that variable in the whole query. Can you please suggest any solution or a better solution for this?

Comment: To confirm Barmar's hypothesis, I would try to execute the query from a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: It looks like it may be doing your subselect for every row, could you try something like this: http://pastebin.com/QXCTXJri

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the value assignment inside your query:

```
select aCol
from myTable, (SELECT @value := 2) as a
where aCol = @value;
```

This way my MariaDB is able to use an index on column 'aCol'